# Capturing portions of text with non-greedy regex

Tags: python, regex, python-2.7

Using re.findall, I want to extract the values assigned to each PCR.

```
>>> z
'PCR-09: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 \r\nPCR-10: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 \r\nPCR-11: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 \r\nPCR-12: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 \r\nPCR-13: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 \r\nPCR-14: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 \r\nPCR-15: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 \r\nPCR-16: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 \r\n

>>> print z
PCR-09: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 
PCR-10: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 
PCR-11: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 
PCR-12: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 
PCR-13: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 
PCR-14: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 
PCR-15: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 
PCR-16: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
```

Initially, I tried this but can someone point out what is wrong with the regex used?

```
>>> re.search('PCR-09:(.*?)', z).groups()
('',)
```

Shouldn't the non-greedy expr `(.*?)` match all characters until it finds a newline?

With a slightly modified regex, I get the desired result:

```
>>> re.search('PCR-09:(.*?)\s\r\n', z).groups()
(' 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00',)
```

On the same lines, this doesn't work:

```
>>> re.findall(r'(PCR-\d+):(.*?)', z)
[('PCR-09', ''), ('PCR-10', ''), ('PCR-11', ''), ('PCR-12', ''), ('PCR-13', ''), ('PCR-14', ''), ('PCR-15', ''), ('PCR-16', ''),
```

But this does:

```
>>> re.findall(r'(PCR-\d+):(.*?)\s\r\n', z,re.DOTALL)
[('PCR-09', ' 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00'), ('PCR-10', ' 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00'), ('PCR-11', ' 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00'), ('PCR-12', ' 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00'), ('PCR-13', ' 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00'), ('PCR-14', ' 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00'), ('PCR-15', ' 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00'), ('PCR-16', ' 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00'),
```

Hoping someone can explain what's wrong with my approach.

Thanks

Comment: It can be easily done using split('\r\n'), y to use regex??

Comment: @Hackaholic I agree. I already have a solution with split() but wanted to understand why my regex is broken.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason `r'PCR-09:(.*?)'` doesn't match what you expect is that non-greedy regexes stop as soon as they're valid.

So `(.*?)` can match `''`, so the regex stops immediately.

In contrast, `r'(PCR-\d+):(.*?)\s\r\n'` is non-greedy, but because it needs to find `\s\r\n', it will force the expansion to work.

I would recommend using a greedy regex that includes only the characters you expect to find: `r'(PCR-\d+):([0-9 ]*)'`.

Answer (score 2):

The pattern `PCR-09:(.*?)` tells Python to match zero or more characters non-greedily after `PCR-09:`. So, it does precisely this and matches zero characters.

You need to have your Regex be *greedy* in order to match everything up to the newline:

```
>>> re.search('PCR-09:(.*)', z).groups()
(' 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 \r',)
>>>
```

Note that your `PCR-09:(.*?)\s\r\n` pattern worked because it told Python to get zero or more characters after `PCR-09:` and **up to** `\s\r\n`.  In other words, get everything between them.

Answer (score 0):

try using: `split`

```
[ x.split(':') for x in z.split('\r\n')]
```

output:

```
[['PCR-09', ' 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 '], ['PCR-10', ' 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 '], ['PCR-11', ' 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 '], ['PCR-12', ' 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 '], ['PCR-13', ' 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 '], ['PCR-14', ' 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 '], ['PCR-15', ' 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 '], ['PCR-16', ' 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 '], ['']]
```

using regex

```
re.findall('(PCR-\d+)(.*)',z)
```